# Laravel mail send got Email address is not verified

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Does anyone came across with this error message when sending mail in Laravel, is there a way to solve this?

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
>   "

I did verified the email addresses and its been "verified" but still came across this error..

Answer (score 3):

Laravel is working fine. You are getting an error message from the AWS mail server.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html

> You are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you have not verified with Amazon SES. If your account is still in the sandbox, you also need to verify the recipient address. For more information, see Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES.
>
> Note that Amazon SES has endpoints in multiple AWS regions, and email address verification status is separate for each AWS region. You must complete the verification process for each sender in the AWS region(s) you want to use. For information about using Amazon SES in multiple AWS regions, see Regions and Amazon SES.

Make special note of that second paragraph. You may need to verify the email for the specific region you are trying to contact, or you need to change your contact address to the correct region.

Comment: I'm using US East N.Virginia (email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com), and my email addresses are verified within this region. Did I missed out anything?

Comment: Just make sure your account is not in a sandbox (it must be in production).|

If you are using a sandbox mode, then it will only send emails to the verified email addresses. Email addresses that are verified by you on Amazon SES -> Configuration -> verified identites

Answer (score 0):

For breif information refer below link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-response-codes.html